# aurora postgres difference between jsonb_path_match and operator @@ gin index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-performance, jsonb, amazon-aurora

I am relatively new to postgressql. We are using aurora postgressql.

I created a GIN index on a table with about 400k rows with one JSONB column.
I created index on JSONB column.

```
CREATE INDEX index1 ON schemanm.tblname USING gin(colname) TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

The version i use is PostgreSQL 12.7

With the below query it does not use the gin index and does a seq scan

```
select count(*) from schemanm.tblname
where  jsonb_path_match(colname,'($.colname.system == "X" ||$.colname.system == "Y")    && $.colname.attra == "attrvala" && $.colname.attrb == "aatrvalb"' )
```

But the below uses index and gives the same result as the above query

```
select count(*) from schemanm.tblname
where  colname @@ '($.colname.system == "X" ||$.colname.system == "Y")  && $.colname.attra == "attrvala" && $.colname.attrb == "aatrvalb"'
```

Is there any difference between the queries or i am doing anything wrong

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like lakh / lac in global forums like this. People living elsewhere have no idea what those mean.

Comment: ok thanks did not realize it, will follow it henceforth

Answer (score 0):

Only operators, not functions, can support indexes.  I think that this is not strictly true anymore with the introduction of "function support functions", but it is still the case for @@ and jsonb_path_match.